# How to extract the columns form a matrix and use them in another predicate, in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to use the results from "extract" (W) in valid_seq which is then use in valid_columns.

I have tried this so far, but it does not work:

```
extract(_,[],[]).
extract(K,[X|Y],[H|L]) :- nth1(K,X,H), extract(K,Y,L).

valid_columns([],[]).
valid_columns([H|L],[X|Y],K) :- b_w(X),
                extract(K,X,W), 
                valid_seq(H,W),
                K1 is K+1,
                valid_columns(L,Y,K1).
```

EDIT:

I am trying to solve a nonogram. 
So from each list of lines, I have to extract the columns to validate them. This is the function "extract"

Once the columns are extracted I need to validate them. 
Ex

```
valid_column([[1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1]],[3,1],1).
false.
```

Here I am asking if the first value in each [] complies to [3,1]. 
In this case should be true. As I have [1 1 1 0 1].

And this is my code:

```
test_cst(0,[0|S],S).   
test_cst(0,[],[]). 
test_cst(N,[1|T],S):- 
                    N1 is N-1,
                    test_cst(N1,T,S).

valid_seq([],[]).      
valid_seq(L,[0|T]):-valid_seq(L,T).      

valid_seq([H|L],[1|T]):-test_cst(H,[1|T],S),valid_seq(L,S). 

b_w([]).
b_w([H|L]) :- H is 0, b_w(L);H is 1, b_w(L).

valid_lines([],[]).
valid_lines([H|L],[X|Y]) :- b_w(X), 
                            valid_seq(H,X),
                            valid_lines(L,Y).


extract(_,[],[]).
extract(K,[X|Y],[H|L]) :- nth1(K,X,H), extract(K,Y,L).

valid_columns([],_,_).
valid_columns([H|L],X,K) :- valid_column(X,H,K),
                            K1 is K+1,
                            valid_columns(L,X,K1).

valid_column(X,H,K) :- b_w(X),
                       extract(K,X,W), 
                       valid_seq(H,W).
```

Comment: What does not work? You do not provide a query? Nor is there an implementation for `b_w/1` or `valid_seq/2` given. Please produce a minimal working example together with a query (or queries) and expected output.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added the rest of the code

Comment: Don't just dump all your code. Identify what doesn't work, then show how to run it, and what you get, and what you expect, and ask if you don't understand why the two are different. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If available, you can put library([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply)) to good use:

```
?- maplist(nth1(I), [[a,b,c],[1,2,3],[x,y,z]], X).
I = 1,
X = [a, 1, x] ;
...
```

I'm suggesting its usage since it simplifies the code, removing irrelevant details, that blurry your *relations*.

For your question, you're passing to b_w/1 a list of lists, while it should be a list. If you have library([yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)) available, b_w/1 can be rewritten like

```
b_w(L) :- maplist([X]>>(X=0;X=1), L).
```